# Icefaces graphicImage supported filetypes

Tags: jsf, icefaces, file-type

Which image filetypes are supported when you pass through a byte[]?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In fact, just anything which matches `image/*`. See [here](http://www.iana.org/assignments/media-types) for a list. You're only dependent on the webbrowser/client used whether it supports the image type.

By the way and to be sure: you can't let the value point to a `byte[]`. It must point to an URL which returns the `byte[]` in question. A servlet is perfectly suitable for this. [Here](http://balusc.blogspot.com/2007/04/imageservlet.html) is a basic example.